# Microsoft Translator Widget - Force Destination Language

Tags: microsoft-translator

How do I force the Microsoft Translator widget to use a specific destination language without depending on the language sent by the browser?

http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the same problem so thought I'd post how I fixed it.

I found that you can simply insert the language letter code into the widget's ajax URL. For example, search the widget code for this:

```
"/ajax/v2/widget.aspx?mode=auto&from=en&layout=ts"
```

Then you can just insert "&to=de" for example, if you want to translate to German. E.g.:

```
"/ajax/v2/widget.aspx?mode=auto&from=en&to=de&layout=ts"
```

As easy as that!