# Microsoft Translator Widget English to German automatic

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-translator

Implemented Microsoft Translator Widget to change the website language English to German forcefully by code. But it's not working.

Microsoft widget translator link: https://www.bing.com/widget/translator

Translation is working only from Widget option menu. I want to acheive this from JavaScript code.

Checked this stackoverflow link: [Microsoft Translator Widget - Force Destination Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403506/microsoft-translator-widget-force-destination-language)

And I changed code for force translation by `&from=en&to=de` adding in parameter. Below is changed function. But not working.

```
setTimeout(function(){
{
    var s=document.createElement('script');
    s.type='text/javascript';s.charset='UTF-8';
    s.src=((location && location.href && location.href.indexOf('https') == 0)?'https://ssl.microsofttranslator.com':'http://www.microsofttranslator.com')+'/ajax/v3/WidgetV3.ashx?siteData=ueOIGRSKkd965FeEGM5JtQ**&ctf=False&ui=true&settings=undefined&from=en&to=de';
    var p=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.documentElement;
    p.insertBefore(s,p.firstChild);
}
},0);
```

Translation is working only from Widget option menu

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Microsoft Translator.

Please know that we're deprecating the Translator Web Widget. To integrate Microsoft Translator in your website you have several options available and the simplest of the options is the Webpage Translator. Visit http://aka.ms/TranslatorWeb for more details.

Let us know if you have additional questions.

Gwenda
Microsoft Translator Team

Comment: do you have a link to any official docs stating that the Translator web widget has been deprecated?